# Free windows tiling manager (similar to ShiftIt or divvy) that can be installed without admin privileges

Tags: macos, window-manager

I usually use [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) to manage, tile, and resize windows. I have come to the point where I really depend on it.

I'm looking for an alternative. It needs to be free, and it needs to be able to be installed and used on OS X 10.7.5 without admin privileges.

What are ways you would recommend to easily tile windows in OS X?

Comment: Could you provide a link for *shift*? I know *divvy* but quick googling doesn't show anything named *shift* in relation to window resizing.

Comment: There are so many options for this, that you cannot define "best", just "preferred" which is opinion based not empirical.  I "prefer" Moom.

Comment: @rsanchezsaez. I included a link

Comment: @DavidWest Thanks, got it now. I don't think there are many options that would not need admin privileges. If you want to provide a good UX I suspect this kind of windows manager would need admin privileges.

Comment: I stand corrected, the answer by Lauri looks like a nice and feasible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use scripts like these:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set b to bounds of window of desktop
    end tell
    set item 1 of b to ((item 3 of b) / 2)
    set item 2 of b to 22
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set bounds of window 1 to b
    end tell
end try
```

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set b to bounds of window of desktop
    set item 2 of b to 22
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set bounds of window 1 to b
    end tell
on error
    try
        tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
            click (button 1 of window 1 where subrole is "AXZoomButton")
        end tell
    end try
end try
```

They don't require access for assistive devices to be enabled (other than for the `on error` block in the second script). They don't work with all windows though, and I don't know what will happen if you have multiple displays.

Automator services are supported out of the box and you can create them on a non-admin account, but as of 10.8 there is a bug where the keyboard shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar. There is also a relatively long delay before Automator services are run.

[image]

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for other ways to assign shortcuts to scripts. I use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), which is free for up to 10 keyboard shortcuts and doesn't require administrator privileges.